# Mapping entities based on type in Doctrine

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got abstract class called Question. 
Now, i've got many types of questions, like OneToChooseFrom or ManyToChooseFrom that extends Question class.

What i want to do, is to store all these types of questions in the single 'questions' table and when i retrieve them, i want them to be mapped properly to OneToChooeFrom class or ManyToChooseFrom class based on question_type column.

I know i can use Single Table Inheritance for that, but i'm already using Class Table Inheritance. So i can't use them both at once.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "description" = "Acme\SurveyBundle\Entity\Description",
 *      "question" = "Acme\SurveyBundle\Entity\Question"
 *     })
 * @ORM\Table(name="survey_item")
 */
abstract class Item
{
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="survey_question")
 */
abstract class Question extends Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="question_type", type="string")
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $questionType;
}

final class OneToChooseFrom extends Question
{
    protected $questionType = 'oneToChooseFrom';
}

final class ManyToChooseFrom extends Question
{
    protected $questionType = 'manyToChooseFrom';
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't push object oriented approach to entities (abstract classes, inheritance and polymorphism), i'm not even sure it is possible (Symfony & Doctrine do after all a lot of "magic").

I would just make one entity class Question with "type" attribute, which would differentiate between different quesiton types.

If you could really profit from OO approach, i would implement some kind of bridge between db entity class and "question model" class...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do nested inheritance, so you could have the single table on `Question` as well as the joined on `Item`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a simple one to many QuestionContainer -< Question or something like that? Then if a QuestionContainer only has one Question, it's a single question. If it has many, it's multiple. Seems a simple problem but your actual use case may be more complex than you've detailed.